# Is there a Python module where I could easily convert mixed fractions into a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just wondering if I could easily convert a mixed number (entered as a number or a string) into a floating point number or an integer. I've looked at the fractions module but it seems like it couldn't do what I want, or I didn't read well.

Just wanted to know if something already exists before I write my own function. Here's what I'm looking for, btw:

```
convert(1 1/2)
```

or

```
convert('1 1/2')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The built-in [`Fraction`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/fractions.html) class does not appear to support mixed fractions like you have, but it wouldn't be too hard to split them up on the space. For example, `1 + fractions.Fraction('1/2')` or a very simplistic

```
def convert(f):
    whole, frac = f.split()
    return int(whole) + fractions.Fraction(frac)
```

Comment: Thanks sir, yeah I could just split(' '), that's all I wanted to know, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the `Mixed` class to extend fractions to do just that.  Source is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonmixedfractionsclass/files/mixed_fractions.py/download).

```
>>> float(Mixed('6 7/8'))
6.875
>>> float(Mixed(1,1,2)) # 1 1/2
1.5
```